# How do I open and display a word document in VB?

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a project, and a main part of it is that it needs to open and display Word 2013 documents. I am using Visual Studio 2012, and coding in Visual Basic. I've tried everything to find the code, but to no avail!

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Documents.Open FileName:="C:\MyFiles\MyDoc.docx", ReadOnly:=True
End Sub
```

I have looked everywhere to find the code for it, so I'm hoping that one of you lovely people can help me!

Cheers, 
Ella

Comment: VB.Net <> VBA, so I swapped tags.

Answer (score 1):

You are using VBA code for a vb.net program, vba and vb.net are not the same thing.

To open a word doc using vb.net try using :

`Process.Start(documentPath)`

If the extention is correct it should open with microsoft word by default.